# Launching REPL in tomcat container

Tags: scala, wicketstuff

I am trying to launch the scala REPL (2.9.1) in tomcat container and getting the following error

```
Failed to initialize compiler: object scala not found.
Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
object programatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.
```

I tried multiple solutions like settings.usejavacp.value = true etc., classpath setting  but still getting the same error. Can somebody please suggest to resolve this issue?

Launching the scala interpreter from wicketstuff console project also giving same error([scala-console-issue-ref](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/issues/28)).

Comment: First of all, are you sure scala-library and scala-compiler jars are loaded?

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with jar loading. I am able to launch REPL from standalone program. There is no issue in that but in web environment its failing.

Comment: Also want to add one more thing, That if i deploy the same war in Jetty server, REPL is getting launch successfully. I can also share the sample web project to demonstrate this issue.